# How to stop the handler which running on interval (1 min)?

Tags: android, performance, android-handler, android-runonuithread

I am developing an application, In which I am sending the device location to the server for every one min. I am using Handler here to schedule my task. After User click the **STOP** button, the handler should stop its execution. I am unable to achieve this. Please find my code below.

```
    public void callSpecficTime() {

    timer = new Timer();
    doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Log.e("TImeOnSchedule", String.valueOf(inTime));
                        if(inTime==5)
                        {
                             new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
                         }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 60000);
}
```

**StopTask** code :

```
    public void stopTask(){

    if(doAsynchronousTask!=null){
        Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
        handler.removeCallbacks(doAsynchronousTask);
     // timer.cancel();
        doAsynchronousTask.cancel();
    }

}
```

I tried `stopService`,`removeCallbacks` but it didn't work. Can anyone provide me solution for this?

**UPDATED**

```
 public void onClickButton(View v)
{
    if(v.getId()==R.id.IBstart)
    {
        callAsynchronousTask();
        callSpecficTime();
    }
    else if(v.getId()==R.idIBstop)
    {
       stopTask();
    }
}
```

This is ** callAsynchronousTask()**

```
 public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

I am posting data twice. First time is when User click the **START** button and then I am start the timer to execute for every one min.

Answer (score 0):

use `purge()` after `cancel()`;

```
public void stopTask(){

    if(doAsynchronousTask!=null){
        Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
        handler.removeCallbacks(doAsynchronousTask);
     // timer.cancel();
        doAsynchronousTask.cancel();
        doAsynchronousTask.purge();
    }

}
```

Comment: time.purge() right? I did that. Still problem is same. 

I am getting `doAsynchronoursTask` as  `null`

Answer (score 0):

1. You should stop the TimerTask first with: `Timer.Cancel()` and `Timer.Purge()`.
2. you can change: `handler.removeCallbacks(doAsynchronousTask);` to `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`.

**Edit:**

Look at your schedule code: `timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 60000);` --> that means you start your `task` immediately and repeated it after 60s.

When I see your `onClickButton` listener, there are 2 tasks which will be executed immediately. As a result, you cant cancel the tasks which are executed. To avoid it, you can call:  `timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 60000, 60000);`

Comment: I tried... Still it is running...

 ` public void stopTask(){

        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
       // new PostDataAsyncTask().cancel(true);
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
     
    }`

Comment: Where are you calling callSpecficTime()?

Comment: When the User click **START** button in UI

Comment: Do you have any solution for this @Kingfisher Phuoc

Comment: @AnishKumar can you post all your code, maybe the problem comes from the other block of code, not stop, start one.